# Puppet class / node dependencies

Tags: puppet

as many people, I have a class dependency problem with puppet. Either one class gets executed too early or I end up in a dependency cycle.

Following setup:

```
node foo:
  require base
  include somethingelse

class base:
  require sources // <- class defines package sources needed for everything

class somethingelse
  apt::builddep { 'foo': } // <- requires some package sources
```

To my understanding, node `foo` gets executed but has a requirement to `base`, so puppet proceeds executing that first. `base`'s first line requires `sources` so puppet will execute that first. `builddep` comes last.

However it does the exact opposite. Sources are getting executed at any time without any logic (like a ressource without dependencies). Many times after builddep which results in a puppet error since the source it needs is not there yet.

When I defined the node dependencies like so:

```
include "base"
include "somethingelse"

Class['base'] -> Class['somethingelse']
```

Or add `Class['sources']` as dependency to builddep, I am getting a dependency cycle similar to this:

```
(Anchor[apt::source::puppetlabs] => Apt::Source[puppetlabs] => Class[Sources] => Class[Base] => Cron[execute-puppet] => Class[Base] => Class[somethingelse] => Apt::Builddep[foo] => Exec[apt-builddep-foo] => Exec[apt_update] => Class[Apt::Update] => Anchor[apt::source::puppetlabs])
```

What am I doing wrong? Can someone point me into the correct direction?
The important thing is, that everything in base (including sources) is getting executed before class `somethingelse` (and therefore builddep)

**EDIT**

Narrowing it down. The problem is, that builddep doesn't require sources to be there. Without any requirements, builddep gets executed before sources are being added, but requires a apt-get update. When adding a requirement to my sources class, I fall into a dependency cycle once again.

Currently trying this one: `Apt::Source <| |> -> Apt::Builddep <| |>` which results in

```
(Anchor[apt::source::puppetlabs] => Apt::Source[puppetlabs] => Apt::Builddep[foo] => Exec[apt-builddep-foo] => Exec[apt_update] => Class[Apt::Update] => Anchor[apt::source::puppetlabs])
```

Comment: Can you provide the configuration that's throwing this error?  There's some strange requirement relationships that it's talking about there, `Class[Base] => Cron[execute-puppet] => Class[Base]` seems particularly wacky. It seems like you've hardcoded a dependency into the internals of the puppetlabs apt module?

Comment: @ShaneMadden I am using puppet masterless. execute-puppet is cron resource which makes sure the puppet pull gets executed all 10 minutes. Base resource: http://pastebin.com/gLvQQ9b6. Node: http://pastebin.com/Zw5EytJK. Somethingelse: http://pastebin.com/SAV3jz8k. I trimmed it down to the important parts

Comment: And sources class here - http://pastebin.com/TCn87sDM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I concluded this to be a bug in apt. `builddep` notifies `apt-get update` instead of requiring it, which doesn't make much sense in my opinion. You want `apt-get update` to be executed **before** installing build dependencies.

I patched apt to require `apt-get update`, which solves my dependency cycle. Submitted a [pull request](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-apt/pull/326) to apt to see what the devs say.